# Are there any LaTeX template for travel guides?

Tags: templates

I would like to make a travel guide that focuses on cities. I am looking for a usable template for a fast creation of this guide. I was thinking about using something similar to the `cookybooky` package. Another way would be to use a beamer... Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: You may add a small list of features that you need in the guide.

Comment: Thank you. Which features do you mean? Is there a something for this idea?

Comment: Features like placing a picture, or multiple pictures. Placing a title. Is a city covering one page or mutliple pages. What about headers/footers? Is there a general layout? Title, plus image to the right, then a short list descript and a bit of text at the bottom.

Comment: I don't know if you will ever read this, but you can *ping* peoplee, using an `at` sign. See @Martin